# Jquery Effect Disappears after some time

Tags: 2013, custom-list

In NewForm.aspx I add `.ms-long{ text-transform:uppercase;} into **PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead** part. So in NewForm.aspx makes upper the text which is entered but doesn't effect to the values. If the entered charachters are lower they looks upper, but in the AllItems.aspx, they looks lower again. So it doesn't make any change.

So I found another solution to make the some column values uppercase.
In PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead, I add this script into the AllItems.aspx. But after 30 minutes or something like that it disappears suddenly.

Why is that happening and how can I solve this  or how can I make script in NewForm.aspx effects to the value?

Thank you.

```
<asp:content contentplaceholderid="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:RssLink runat="server"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/../../../jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="/../../../Style Library/1.7.2.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
          $(document).ready(function () {

            $('.ms-listviewtable tr').each(function() {
                $(this).find('td:eq(7)').css('text-transform','uppercase');
                $(this).find('td:eq(11)').css('text-transform','uppercase');
            });
        });
</script>
</asp:content>
```

Comment: could you explain a bit more? do you mean that you have the page open for a peroid of time and left open.... then the js doesnt work or you open it and then leave then open it again and its not working?

Comment: When I open the page it works fine but after a while it works like there is no script. With refreshing page or reopen the browser doesn't effect it,just the time effects.

Comment: How did you finally solve the problem?

Comment: I marked my answer.Yours didn't work for the masterpage. I guess I did something wrong. I 'll create another question about it soon for the master page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me. It makes always repeat itself in every 1000 miliseconds.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
          setInterval(function () {
                $('.ms-listviewtable tr').each(function() {
                $(this).find('td:eq(5)').css('text-transform','uppercase');
                $(this).find('td:eq(11)').css('text-transform','uppercase');
            });            
            }, 1000);


        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks as if the table gets rewritten by a timeout. Are you regularly updating the component?
If so you might want to try attaching an appropriate event handler to capture that, sg. like:

```
$( 'body' ).on( 'DOMSubtreeModified', function(e) {
    $( '.ms-listviewtable tr').each(function() {
            $(this).find('td:eq(7)').css('text-transform','uppercase');
            $(this).find('td:eq(11)').css('text-transform','uppercase');
    });
} );
```

Comment: I found the solution but just curioused.  I use "each" so how can I make it work?

Comment: I updated the code including your snippet... I still can't comment on your answer (too few points) So let me advocate for the `DOMSubtreeModified` event handler rather than a `setInterval`. Latter will always have a delay (one second in your case) if you decrease the interval to low you eat up resources.

Comment: It worked for now but I have to write you back in 1 hour again for the result . Because the problem was that the code start to dont work after some time :)

Comment: You can test immediately by changing the content of the table yourself. E.g. In Firefox use Firebug check youtube for some videos on that or run this in the browser console: `$( '.ms-listviewtable tr' ).find('td:eq(7)').text( 'somechange')` this should trigger the event.

Comment: It had been 10 minutes and again not working. It's weird.

Comment: I see, most probably the DOM that gets rewritten includes the element that you attach the event handler on, thus it doesn't get called. I changed the solution in the code to attach it at body level. Ideally you find the innermost DOM element that does not get changed and attach the event there.

Answer (score 1):

i dont know if this would work but worth a try:

for some reason your js is lost in memory:

have the code within a js file and call it from the masterpage!

```
      $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.ms-listviewtable tr').each(function() {
            $(this).find('td:eq(7)').css('text-transform','uppercase');
            $(this).find('td:eq(11)').css('text-transform','uppercase');
        });
    });
```

you will need to set some logic so that it doesnt execute on every page that has a table tho!

you could do the same but have a reference to the file within the aspx instead!

**EDIT**

in your masterpage look for a row like

```
<SharePoint:Scriptlink ID="Scriptlink2" runat="server" Name="/_layouts/LifeInSharePoint.Metro/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" Language="javascript"/>
```

just change the id to a greater number and the name to the location of the new js file where its stored!

Comment: I don't know to call a js from masterpage.So I need time. I'll try it when I have time and write the result.

Comment: just ammended my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("customOnLoadFunction");` instead of JQuery's `$(document).ready(function()`..

```
function customOnLoadFunction() {
   $('.ms-listviewtable tr').each(function() {
       $(this).find('td:eq(7)').css('text-transform','uppercase');
       $(this).find('td:eq(11)').css('text-transform','uppercase');
   });
}
```

You can read more about it here:
[_SPBODYONLOADFUNCTIONNAMES IN SHAREPOINT VS. JQUERY’S DOCUMENT READY](http://www.stephanrocks.com/2011/10/05/_spbodyonloadfunctionnames-in-sharepoint-vs-jquerys-document-ready/)

**UPDATE**

Try this:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () { customOnLoadFunction(); }, "sp.core.js");
```

Comment: It didn't work. And also changed "$" to "jQuery"

Comment: Please check the updated answer

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: Actually, the function is called but the codes inside of it didn't work.:/